# Letter ü changes to ь while applying macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which enters a simple formula to a cell but, Russian speaking colleagues have a problem as you can see below. The letter "ü" is converted to cyrillic letter "ь" which is a problem and I believe it is due to their language settings. The cells which are not written by the macro are not affected by this.

Code:

> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =_
>
> "=IF(AND(R20C8=""**ü**"",R22C8=""**ü**""),""OK"",""NOT OK"")"

Result:

> =IF(AND($H$20="**ь**",$H$22="**ь**"),"OK","Not OK")

How can I make sure that the letter doesn't change regardless of the language settings?

Thank you,

Comment: Check if `Chr$(252)` instead of `ü` works: `"=IF(AND(R20C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """,R22C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """),""OK"",""NOT OK"")"`

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I think this would work but, it makes my code too long and I couldn't split it into two lines because it is one really long formula.
For now, I wrote the formula in a hidden sheet and will take it from there. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: *"it makes my code too long and I couldn't split it into two lines because it is one really long formula."* I don't understand this argument. If this works it is definitely possible to do so and any long formula can be split into multiple lines in VBA. It is just splitting strings into multiple lines. Definitely working.

Comment: How can I split this code? 

`"=IF(AND(R20C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """,R22C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """),""OK"",""Not OK"")"`

I tried to use line-continuation character ( _) like this: 
`"=IF(AND(R20C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """, _
R22C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """),""OK"",""Not OK"")"`

but, it's giving me this error:
`Compile error: 
Expected: end of statement`

So, I thought maybe it's not possible to split the AND() conditions. What am I missing?

Comment: Try it like this: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(R20C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """," & _
        "R22C8=""" & Chr$(252) & """),""OK"",""Not OK"")"`.

Comment: Thank you @Domenic. Splitting like that works.

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!